# Disable react toolbox ripple

Tags: reactjs, material-design, react-toolbox

I'm using react-toolbox's port of Google's material design library and I wonder if it's possible to disable the ripple effect.

<s>I've been trying to hide it with css using the following selector but that didn't work.</s>

```
[data-react-toolbox="ripple"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

**EDIT:** As it turned out this actually worked and I was too dumb.

Because it vanishes so fast it is difficult for me to inspect the ripple dom element in chrome.

<s>A css solution would be great but it would be much better to not render the ripple at all for performance reasons.</s>

**EDIT:** Is it possible to remove the ripple completely?

Any suggestions are welcome.